# How to export an SQL-Database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

in phpmyadmin to my local disk? I don't see a field where I can specify the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin offers many export options. Just click on the database and select "Export" from the menu. There you will be able to save the file (offered for download), or get the export queries in a edit box.

If you want to programatically export a mysql database, use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem was that in the german version of phpmyadmin it's called "Senden" (what just means send) and not "Save as file", so I wondered where it would be sent and I wasn't allowed to store Data on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In the Export tab, select "Save as file".

Answer (score 0):

Below the Options Panel there is an second panel with an checkbox called "save as file" or "send" or similar. You have to check that checkbox. Then the file will be offered for Download like if you download anything else from the Internet.